# Multi selection on System.Windows.Forms.DataGrid (CF)

Tags: c#, compact-framework, multi-select

Is there a way to do multi-selction on with the standard datagrid?  (I am using the compact framework.)

---

This is what I ended up doing:

```
readonly List<int> _selectedRows = new List<int>();
private void dataGrid1_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    int c = dataGrid1.CurrentRowIndex;
    if (_selectedRows.Contains(c))
    {
        dataGrid1.UnSelect(c);
        _selectedRows.Remove(c);
        // Take focus off the current row if I can
        if (_selectedRows.Count > 0)
            dataGrid1.CurrentRowIndex = _selectedRows[0];
    }
    else
    {
        _selectedRows.Add(c);
    }
    foreach (int rowIndex in _selectedRows)
    {
        dataGrid1.Select(rowIndex);
    }
}
```

Kind of a poor man's mulit select, but it works.

Answer (score 0):

Not inherently, no.  You'd have to handle the SelectedRows yourself and [custom draw it](http://blogs.msdn.com/netcfteam/archive/2006/04/25/583542.aspx).